# How to make a component using <TableRow/>, for breaking up <Table/> component in Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to make a component for the rows in Ant Design Table, where each component will have their own state and based on that table rows will be shown. is it possible?

if possible how can I do it? an example will be helpful.

*I tried the following example but it's showing 'No Data'*

> in item.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TableRow from "antd";

class Item extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  dataSource = [
    {
      key: "1",
      details: "test",
      price: 50
    }
  ];

  render() {
    return <TableRow dataSource={this.dataSource} />;
  }
}
export default Item;
```

> and in itemlist.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Table } from "antd";
import Item from "./item";

class ItemList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  columns = [
    {
      title: "Item Details",
      dataIndex: "details",
      key: "details"
    },
    {
      title: "Price",
      dataIndex: "price",
      key: "price"
    }
  ];

  render() {
    return (
      <Table column={this.columns}>
        <Item key="1" />
      </Table>
    );
  }
}

export default ItemList;
```

Comment: go ahead, what stops you?

Comment: @Alex how can I do it?. if you could please provide an example or some links that will be very helpful.

Comment: you described it very well - just create inner components and define there `getDerivedStateFromProps` which will track the props passed from table. Also, you need to provide your own attempt first, and only then I can help you with particular issue you faced.

Comment: @Alex I have edited and provided my attempt so far, please provide me some way out to resolve this.

Comment: now it's more clear, but still not obvious what do you need to define per row. Also, `dataSource` should be applied to `Table`, as well as `columns`.

Comment: so your question is whether to display the row based on data, right? Or you're asking about whether to display some cell based on data?

Comment: @Alex my current requirement is to display rows with their own state, but also some knoladge on cell with their own state, may be required in future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187913/discussion-between-alex-and-smaranjit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not totally get your requirements, but from I understand: you can define `render` in [column definition](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column), and there you'll get an row item:

```
class ItemList extends Component {
  dataSource = [
    {
      key: "1",
      details: "test",
      price: 50
    }
  ];

  columns = [
    {
      title: "Item Details",
      dataIndex: "details",
      render: (text, record, index) => <Item {...record} />  
      key: "details"
    }
  ];

  render() {
    return (
      <Table columns={this.columns} dataSource={this.dataSource} />
    );
  }
}
```

If you just need to not show some rows based on data, you can filter `dataSource` accordingly.